# I need to assign a variable name "package" in my pojo (java) class so that it can be binded through object mapper class, but it is showing error

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to make a pojo class in which I am binding a json object using ObjectMapper. I have to use a variable name

```
private String package;
```

but the above line showing me error. Is there any solution so that I can use this variable name package.

Comment: You cannot use [Reserved Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) in Java to name stuff in your code. It's prohibited

Comment: the above line showing me error. This really doesn't tell us anything. your problem is that 'package' is a keyword, and thus can not be used as a name for a variable

Comment: `package` is a reserved keyword. You can change slightly and use words like `_package`, `Package` and so on.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware about the reserved keywords of java. But I was asking whether is there any solution for my problem.

Answer (score 5):

as said in previous comment, package cannot be used in java as a variable name but you can annotate the variable to still use that name in JSON

```
@JsonProperty("package")
private String packageName
```

Comment: I think this is the exact solution to my problem. Thanks @Wisthler

Answer (score 3):

The word *package* is a keyword and you can't use it as a name for variable.

[Here's a link to a list of keywords in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Answer (score 0):

Reserved words are words that can not be used as names of objects or variables in a Java program because they are already used by the syntax of the Java programming language.

*Package* is also a Reserved word.

If you try to use any of the following words as identifiers in your Java programs, you will get an error.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the names to declare that are used in Java language.